# Property 'onClick' is missing in type '{ rating: any; }' but required in type 'RatingType'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple rating component in reactjs with typescript as follows

Rating.js

```
export type RatingType = {
  rating: number,
  onClick: (x: number) => void
  style?: React.CSSProperties,
  prod?: any
}

const Rating: React.FC <RatingType> = ({ rating, onClick, style }) => {
  return (
    <>
      //do something here
    </>
  );
};

export default Rating;
```

I would like to use this rating component in another component but without the onClick function  like this below

```
import Rating from "./Rating";
function Demo() {
  return (
    //logic goes here
    <Rating rating={item.ratings}  />
  )
}

export default Demo
```

But I get the following error

```
Property 'onClick' is missing in type '{ rating: any; }' but required in type 'RatingType'.
```

How can I make the onClick function option when defining the type RatingType?

Comment: the same way as you already have with `style` and `prod`: add a `?` after the prop name

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `onClick` to be required, just make it optional like this:

```
export type RatingType = {
  rating: number,
  onClick?: (x: number) => void // <- Add question mark there
  style?: React.CSSProperties,
  prod?: any
}

const Rating: React.FC <RatingType> = ({ rating, onClick, style }) => {
  return (
    <>
      //do something here
    </>
  );
};

export default Rating;
```

Comment: I tried that but I get this : `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`

Comment: @TheDeadMan Then do a type check such as `if (typeof onClick === 'function')` or live dangerously by coercing it to a function `(onClick as (x: number) => void)()`

Comment: I think the solution here should be optiona chaining where I am using onClick I need to do it like this  `onClick={() => onClick?.(i)}`

Comment: and that solves the problem adding ? on type and wherever I wana use onclick I do it as I suggested above, thanks

Comment: Well yea... it doesn't seem like you were passing in the onClick function from the parent `Demo` that will definitely result in that error

Comment: I have many components  other I am using onClick and on another am not using it

Comment: Got it... your question you didn't include a snippet of how you were calling the `onClick` prop.

Answer (score 1):

To make `onClick` optional just change `RatingType` to:

```
export type RatingType = {
  rating: number,
  onClick?: (x: number) => void, // NOTE the ? to make property optional
  style?: React.CSSProperties,
  prod?: any
}
```

Note the `?` after the `onClick`

Comment: Tried that but I get this error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined`

Comment: If you try to consume that `onClick` from inside and is not defined yet (like in this case), try adding a `?` to the function or avoid calling it if it is undefined

Comment: yes solved it like that